# Object fails to render after updating unrelated Poolable objects

Tags: java, libgdx, game-engine

The code is relatively self explanatory. I am making a little action game. The game renders Poolable blob enemies on the screen, they render just fine, attack my player, die after a certain amount of hits. For some reason, uncommenting the "updateEffects()" method causes the blob enemies to stop rendering after being hit once.

```
public void render() {
Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
tilesRavis.setView(cam);
tilesRavis.render();
sbatch = (SpriteBatch) tilesRavis.getBatch();

sbatch.begin();

playerbar.update(world.getp1().currentHP, world.getp1().maxHP);
manabar.update(world.getp1().currentMP, world.getp1().maxMP); 
drawBars();
sbatch.end(); 

drawNewPlayer(world.getp1());
//  updateEffects();

drawDemBlobs();

cam.position.set(world.getp1().getPosition().x, world.getp1().getPosition().y, 0);
cam.update();
guicam.update();
}

//carries out animation
private void drawBlob(Blob blob){
    TextureRegion temp2 = GameAssets.gooSprite.move.getKeyFrame(blob.getEnemyTime(), true);
    switch (blob.getBlobState()){
    case Patrol:
        temp2 = GameAssets.gooSprite.move.getKeyFrame(blob.getEnemyTime(), true);
        break;
    case Pursue:
        temp2 = GameAssets.gooSprite.move.getKeyFrame(blob.getEnemyTime(), true);
        break;
    case AtkDraw:
        temp2 = GameAssets.gooSprite.move.getKeyFrame(blob.getEnemyTime(), true);
        break;
    case AtkWindow:
        temp2 = GameAssets.gooSprite.move.getKeyFrame(blob.getEnemyTime(), true);
        break;
    case AtkRecovery:
        temp2 = GameAssets.gooSprite.move.getKeyFrame(blob.getEnemyTime(), true);
        break;

    }
    Batch batch = tilesRavis.getBatch();
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(temp2, blob.getPosition().x, blob.getPosition().y, 1, 1);
    batch.end();
}

public void drawDemBlobs(){
    for(int i = 0; i < world.getaBlob().size; i++){
        Blob blob = world.getaBlob().get(i);        
        drawBlob(blob);

        if(blob.isEffectHit()){
            spawnEffect(blob.getPosition(), GameAssets.gooHit, 1, 500); //create effect
            blob.setEffectHit(false);
        }
    }
}


private void updateEffects(){
for(int b = 0;  b < effectArray.size; b++){
    Effect effect = effectArray.get(b);
            if(effect.getLife().hasCompleted()){ 
                effectArray.removeIndex(b);
                effectPool.free(effect);
            }           
        }
}

public void drawEffect(Effect effect){
    TextureRegion temp = new TextureRegion();
    temp = effect.animation.getKeyFrame(effect.getStateTime(), false);
    Batch batch = tilesRavis.getBatch();
    batch.begin();
    batch.draw(temp, effect.getPosition().x, effect.getPosition().y, effect.size, effect.size);
    batch.end();

}

public void spawnEffect(Vector2 position, Animation animation, float size, long life){
    Effect effect = effectPool.obtain();
    effect.init(position, animation, size, life);
    effectArray.add(effect);

}
```

Drawing the effect (a little blob blood splash) seems to have no, uh, effect, on whether the blob stops rendering or not.

Answer (score 0):

You call removeIndex(b) while going over the array from the start, which will cause bad things to happen.

Change your for loop in the updateEffects method to the following:

```
for(int b = effectArray.size - 1;  b >= 0; b--){
 // stuff
}
```

Comment: I thought this would be it for sure, unfortunately it didn't change a things, still behaves the same. :/

Comment: Then I would suggest you try to debug it - look if the effectPool.free and effectPool.obtain methods are working correctly.